# Magento: Add Extra Page to Customer Section

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to implement a simple page which will be part of the customer section on my test website, I want the page to appear on the following link:

```
domain.com/customer/requests
```

Just like other examples already in place by default:

```
domain.com/customer/account
domain.com/customer/forgotpassword
domain.com/customer/account/create
```

I've have tried so many different suggestions but I'm not getting anywhere and just receiving 404 errors.

I know how to control the page content, but I'm struggling to actually link my template page to a real URL.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/requests" name="requests" template="customer/requests/index.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this:

1. For developers: create a custom module that overrides the customer controller and adds `requestsAction()`.

   - If this is what you are doing, then I
     need to see some more information, specifically your `config.xml`
     file and controller file, to help you further. If you don't know how to do this, then I'd recommend reading up on some tutorials for creating modules and overriding controllers. Though, if you're not savy with PHP, or you don't want to do all that programming, then I'd recommend #2.
2. For admins: create a CMS page and add a redirect to it:

   - Create a CMS page, name it "customer-requests". Add your content. Save.
   - Go to `Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management`.
   - Click `Add Url Rewrite`
   - Select `custom`.
   - Set these values in the fields:

     ```
     Request path: customer/requests
     Target path: customer-requests
     ID path: customer-customer-requests-redirect (or whatever you want, just has to be unique)
     ```
   - Click `Save` and clear your cache.